# Problem with using conditionals on nested Playa children tag

Tags: playa

Any idea why this conditional is not working? If I remove 'if' the code renders desired result.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="festivals" url_title="festival-2013" limit="1"}
        {exp:playa:children channel="films" var_prefix="films"}

        {if '{films:film_language}' != ""}
            {films:exp:playa:children channel="languages" var_prefix="filmlanguage" backspace="1"} 
                {filmlanguage:title},
            {/films:exp:playa:children}
        {/if}

            {/exp:playa:children}
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

The single tag `{films:film_language}` will never return empty. Try it by itself in your template and see what you get. A `0`, I think (don't remember).

If there's nothing for the Playa field to parse, if it's empty, then it won't show, so just do this:

```
    {films:film_language}
        {exp:playa:children channel="languages" var_prefix="filmlanguage" backspace="1"} 
            {filmlanguage:title},
        {/exp:playa:children}
    {/films:film_language}
```

Does that solve it for you?

Comment: Still no go. Now it looks like it doesn't process tags inside {films:film_language}. I get this rendered: {filmlanguage:title}, {filmlanguage:title}, {/exp:playa:children}

Comment: Can you clarify what you channel/channel field set up is?